# WMI ping failed (0x80041001 - Generic error)

Tags: windows, wmi, ping

I have an application which uses WMI to perform several tasks, one of them is pinging remote machines. For ping I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address='192.168.0.1' AND Timeout=3000 AND StatusCode=0
```

On several systems this works perfectly right. But on some machines this query returns 0x80041001 - "Generic WMI Error". When I execute this query manually with wbemtest.exe, I get the same error and the following 'Description':

> Failed to send echo, IcmpSendEcho2 failed.

What can be the reason of this error, and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Sounds to me it is trying to tell you that the query failed because the StatusCode isn't 0.  Which would be pretty normal.  Remove StatusCode=0 from the query and try again.

Comment: If StatusCode will be not 0, query must return no rows (as it do on machines where it works). But I tryed to leave only 'Address' in query (remove Timeout and StatusCode) - the error is the same.

Comment: [This link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/trentsh/archive/2012/05/22/wmi-amp-bits-errors.aspx), combined with yours, indicates this is WMI's way of telling you there's a communications error. Adding some flow/error checking might help. Do you have such code? What script language are you using?

Comment: @Lizz Interesting link, but do you think that BITS (file transfer service) could be used in plain ping job (ICMP request)? In any case I will check bitsadmin when I get to one of those 'bad' machines. Answering your questions: error checking is small, but I can reproduce error with the same query and wbemtest utility, and get all info. In my application I use C++ & COM.

Comment: First, no, I don't think it's using BITS, but logs should tell. This MS page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx on Win32_PingStatus class _should_ contain *all* the error and status codes. Seems it doesn't. If it's working on some hosts but not others, what's the OS of the ones where it fails? The support page says it works on 2003 & XP - no other OS mentioned. Curious what you'll find...